# Why does tflite not do any classification?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, tensorflow-lite

I wanted to use tflite in my Flutter app to show classification of a chosen image. However, when I run my program and select any image, there is no output from the Tflite.runModelOnImage. Here's the code:

```
class _NewHistoryItemPageState extends State<NewHistoryItemPage> {
  PickedFile? _image;
  bool _loading = false ;
  List<dynamic>? _outputs;
  String res = "no results yet";


  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    loadModel();
  }

  //Load the Tflite model
  loadModel() async {
    await Tflite.loadModel(
      model: 'assets/tflite_model/model_float.tflite',
      labels: 'assets/tflite_model/labels.txt',
    );

    print('my output: ${res}');
  }

  classifyImage(image) async {
    var output = await Tflite.runModelOnImage(
      path: image.path,
      numResults: 2,
      threshold: 0.5,
      imageMean: 127.5,
      imageStd: 127.5,
    );


    setState(() {
      _loading = false;
      //Declare List _outputs in the class which will be used to show the classified class name and confidence
      _outputs = output;
      res = _outputs![0]["label"];
      print('my output: ${res}');
    });

    print('my output: ${res}');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: Text(res)),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: openGallery,
        backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
        child: Icon(Icons.image),
      ),
    );
  }
  
  Future openGallery() async {
    var image = await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      _image = image;
    });
    classifyImage(image);

  }
}
```

I tried to follow some tutorial on tflite, though couldn't find out what the problem is.

Edit: It seems like my model isn't downloading. Here's the error message:

PlatformException(Failed to load model, flutter_assets/assets/tflite_model/model_float.tflite, java.io.FileNotFoundException: flutter_assets/assets/tflite_model/model_float.tflite

What might be a cause for this?

Comment: if you add `res = await Tflite.loadModel` what is the value of res? Also check their example code https://github.com/shaqian/flutter_tflite/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart

Comment: Checked, it looks like my model is not uploaded for some reason